# How to use both Sequential and Non Sequential Features with Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, keras, lstm, sequential, nonsequential

My dataset has multiple features containing both sequential data and non sequential data.

How can I concatenate or use them together in a model to work it out with all the features rather than just the sequential or the non sequential ones?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be a similar answer in Data Science stack exchange. Unfortunately it doesn't seem like there's a simple solution.
https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/17139